# Android - Slide FrameLayout up and have it stop

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I have a `FrameLayout` with some UI elements that is covering a `ListView`. I want to click a button and have the `FrameLayout` slide up to reveal the list underneath.

So far I can get the top layout to slide up but after the side animation it instantly returns to its original spot.

```
 public void showHistory(View v) {

     FrameLayout mainView = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainView);
     Animation slideUp = setLayoutAnim_slideup(); 
     mainView.startAnimation(slideUp);

 }

 public Animation setLayoutAnim_slideup() {

        AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

        Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -0.8f);
        animation.setDuration(400);
        set.addAnimation(animation);

        return animation;

}
```

**How can I just make it stay in the same place that the animation stopped it?**

Comment: You may try adding animation.setFillAfter(true); to your setLayoutAnim_slideup() function. See if this works.

Comment: That worked! Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `animation.setFillAfter(true)` to your `setLayoutAnim_slideup()` .
function.

Edit-

```
public void showHistory(View v) {

        FrameLayout mainView = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainView);
        AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
        // Using property animation
        ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mainView,
                "translationY", 0f, -0.8f);
            animation.setDuration(2000);
        set.play(animation);
        set.start();

    }
```

Comment: Do you know why, after the animation is complete, that view that was animated no longer responds to touches?

Comment: I am not sure .I will suggest you to use property animation instead of view animations. In View animations -  if you animated a button to move across the screen, the button draws correctly, but the actual location where you can click the button does not change, so you have to implement your own logic to handle this. In Property Animations -  these constraints are completely removed, and you can animate any property of any object (Views and non-Views) and the object itself is actually modified.

Comment: @NicHubbard : please check the sample.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a test.